# Get attachment file link

Tags: attachments

I'm building a theme that generates on the home template a link to the PDF attached to the post (it will be only PDF files).

I found a solution to check if the post has a PDF attached. The goal is to create a link that downloads the file, on the home (blog) template.

Here's what I currently have

```
function leoni_get_attachment() {
    global $post; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    );

    $attachments     = get_posts($args);
    $attachment_link = wp_get_attachment_url();

    if ($attachments) {
        echo '<a href="'. $attachment_link .'">Download</a>';
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried using `get_attached_file()` without success.

Answer (score 7):

Well, there is a WP function for that.

wp_get_attachment_url

It takes attachment id as argument, so you can use it like in following example:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url( 12 );
```

This will echo url to attachment which id is 12.

You can find more info and examples on Codex page:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: Thanks for pointing @Krzysiek but I tried in many ways that function and somehow it doesn't work on the home template.

Comment: @audaz802 Wellness, it works, because WordPress uses it in many places. Can you show your code? How did you use it?

Comment: Sure, I updated my question.

Comment: OK. But you have to pass attachment ID as param for this function to work. How should it know which attachment's url to return? And second thing... get_posts returns array of posts, not one of them. So you'll need some loop in your code...

Answer (score 1):

```
 $attachment_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachments[0]->ID );
```

Try replacing your link with, this one. You need to pass an argument to get the url which is the attachment ID.